# Tomcat does not clean the abandoned connections after abandonedtimeout

Tags: java, tomcat7, connection-pooling

I have an application running in tomcat 7. The application uses tomcat connection pool to connect to Oracle. Some of the connections are not manually closed in the application. Hence these connections will not be returned to connection pool. The following properties are set in context.xml

```
maxWait="5000"
maxIdle="15"
maxActive="90"
removeAbandoned=true
removeAbandonedTimeout=60
logAbandoned=true
```

This should mean that the open connections should be eligible to be removed after 60 secs. So when the cleaner thread runs it should clear those connections. I have not set timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis. Hence the default(5 secs) should be used as the interval for evictions.
But surprisingly, these open connections are not cleaned every 5 secs.

Question1
The cleaning takes about 4-5 hours to occur. During high load its about 20 mins. If the cleaner thread runs every 5 secs, then why doesnt Tomcat clean the abandoned connections every 5 secs?

Question2
Below given is the log printed in catalina.out when the abandoned connection is removed.

```
"org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace$AbandonedObjectException: DBCP object created 2014-08-13 04:10:11 by the following code was never closed:"
```

There are a huge number of such logs with the same time of object creation as shown. But I am pretty sure there were no connection objects created during that time because there was no one accessing the application at that time. Does this time signify something else?